# Java P2P - what options are there?

Tags: java, p2p

I'm looking to write a decentralised application that would run over some kind of peer to peer framework. I have fairly limited requirements:

- search for peers offering a particular service
- advertise services
- connect directly to other nodes
- operate across NATs (so support relay and rendevous)

I know about JXTA, but what other options are there? JXTA seems like a bit of a nightmare to implement - is there anything else that maybe offers a less complete protocol stack in exchange for simplicity and ease of deployment?

Thanks

Comment: The "operate across NAT" is non-trivial, especially combined with the "advertise services".  Perhaps you should be more descriptive about what these service are to be.

Comment: to Anuruddha: can you please give a simple example for transfer file to other computer using pastry so that i can start from there. I'm also in a same problem...

Answer (score 2):

JXTA is something matured p2p overlay implementation. I'm using Pastry (its also written in java). Surf Pastry and have fun...:)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) (Jabber) could solve. Its not true P2P (it has servers), but the servers are inter-linked and mature.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at pne of theses options :

- Azureus : http://azureus.sourceforge.net/
- XNAP: http://xnap.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html